# Difference and sum of two odd numbers raised to even powers individually

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I noticed that modulus of difference of any two odd numbers raised to even powers individually is always divisible by 4 and their sum is always congruent to 2(mod 4).

Example

|77^2 - 59^4| = 12111432 ≡ 0(mod 4)

53^2 + 15^6 = 11393434 ≡ 2(mod 4)

I haven't been able to prove that though. Can anyone provide a proof?

Has this been discussed before because I couldn't find any information about this anywhere on the internet of in MSE.

Thank you

Comment: The square of an odd number is always 1 modulo 4: $(2n+1)^2=4n(n+1)+1$.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek I didn't know that. Thanks!!

Comment: By the dupe $\,n\,$ odd $\Rightarrow n^2\equiv 1\pmod 4\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\text{To prove this, you have to know that the square of any odd number is always 1 modulo 4.}\\\text{The proof is shown below. }$
$$\text{Let 2n+1 be the odd number, }$$
$$(2n+1)^2$$
$$=4n^2+4n+1$$
$$=4(n^2+n)+1$$
$$\text{Therefore, }(2n+1)^2\equiv1(\operatorname{mod}4)$$
$\text{Because }(2n+1)^2\text{ is still a odd number,}\\\text{So }(2n+1)^n\equiv1(\operatorname{mod}4)\text{ when n is an even number. }\\\text{Now we can get into your finding.}\\\text{From above, we know that all odd numbers to even powers can be represented by }4n+1. $
$$\text{Let 4n+1 be the first number, 4k+1 be the second number, }$$
$$(4n+1)-(4k+1)=4(n-k)\equiv0(\operatorname{mod}4)$$
$$(4n+1)+(4k+1)=4(n+k)+2\equiv2(\operatorname{mod}4)$$
$\text{Now, these are proved. }$

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).